# Why can't I use a Keras model like an tf op in my flow graph

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am trying to use my pre-trained keras model somewhere in my computational flow-graph in a tf session, so I've tried this simplified graph and I still get the same errors.

```
model = load_model('models/vtcnn3.h5')

input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1,*x_test.shape[1:]))
output = model(input)

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()

guess_0 = sess.run(output, {input:x_test[0:1]} )
```

when the session runs I get a large traceback that eventually says

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Error while reading resource variable dense2/kernel from Container: localhost. This could mean that the variable was uninitialized. Not found: Container localhost does not exist. (Could not find resource: localhost/dense2/kernel)
     [[node sequential/dense2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp (defined at code/soq.py:114) ]]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node sequential/dense2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp:
 dense2/kernel (defined at code/soq.py:111)

Original stack trace for 'sequential/dense2/MatMul/ReadVariableOp':
  File "code/soq.py", line 114, in <module>
    output = model(input)
  File "/Users/yaba/miniconda3/envs/cs1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 634, in __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
.
.
.
.
```

`dense2` is the name of a layer in my model. When I make other changes to the flow-graph, the traceback puts the error into a different layer of my model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Srihari Humbardwadi for the initialization answer, that fixed the error I was getting but now the output of the network was different than if I used `model.predict(...)`!

If you want to load a Keras model fmor a file and use it in your Tensorflow graph, you must set your `tf.Session()` into the Keras backend, THEN initialize variables, THEN load the Keras model as shown below

```
sess = tf.Session()

# make sure keras has the same session as this code BEFORE initializing
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)

# Do this BEFORE loading a keras model
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)


model = models.load_model('models/vtcnn3.h5')


input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=(1,*x_test.shape[1:]))
output = model(input)


guess_0 = sess.run(output, feed_dict={input:x_test[0:1]} )
```

This `guess_0` will now be the same as if you were to do

```
model = models.load_model('models/vtcnn3.h5')
guess_0 = model.predict(x_test[0:1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to run your inputs through your Keras model, you need to initialize the variables. The following code works fine with `tensorflow==1.14.0`

```
import tensorflow as tf

model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50()

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    random_image, _ = sess.run([tf.random.normal(shape=[1, 224, 224, 3]), init_op])
    outputs = sess.run(model.output, feed_dict={model.input:random_image})
```

Comment: This worked!!!! Thank you so much! I'm using tensorflow v2.0, so I had to use compatibility options. I did `init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()` then `sess.run(init_op)`

Comment: Now I'm getting a different result when using the tf session, than if I use `model.predict(...)`. Do you know how to fix that as well?